# PHP - Get other extensions of file

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and need help.

I have a folder with files like:

```
D:\fold\A.pdf
D:\fold\A.doc
D:\fold\A.xls
D:\fold\A.txt
```

for some work I'm using the `A.txt` file, now I need to echo other files as well from the same folder path.

Like if `A.txt` is searched echo

```
A.pdf
A.xls
A.doc
```

I tried something:

```
$filename = basename($value, ".txt"); //$value has the whole path and the extension is .txt
echo $path = pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_DIRNAME) ."\\". $filename;// prints the path & base name.
```

But how to print the extensions other than '.txt'?

---

Thanks for the suggestions and I tried something like this,

```
$value = "D:\\Fold\\A.txt";
$filename = basename($value, ".txt"); 
$path = pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_DIRNAME) ."\\". $filename; 
foreach (glob($path."*") as $filenames)  
 {   
  if (!strpos($filenames, ".txt"))
  echo $filenames; 
 }
```

This the right answer.

Comment: [`glob`](http://php.net/glob)

Comment: Hi deceze,

If I use glob I'll need to hard code the extensions, but I want the other files to echo on runtime.

Comment: Huh? `glob('somefile.*')` is what you want.

Comment: Hi please see my question I have edited it and added some of my work, please reply to it.

Comment: @PranayB did you read the documentation to `glob`? @deceze gave you the link, all you need now is to `echo` everything from the array that you got returned from the `glob('somefile.*')`

Comment: Btw do you want to search only for files that have same name but different extension than the given one or you want to search for all other files in the folder that doesn't have `.txt` extension. It's a bit unclear from the given example output compared to your codes.

Comment: I want to search only for files that have same name but different extension than the given one. Means `A.txt` and `A.pdf` are the files then I want to `echo` `A.pdf`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you all for all the help and finally the whole code for excluding `.txt` file and echoing the needed files is :

```
$value = "D:\\Fold\\A.txt";
$filename = basename($value, ".txt"); 
$path = pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_DIRNAME) ."\\". $filename; 
foreach (glob("$path.*") as $filenames)  
 {   
  if (!strpos($filenames, ".txt"))
  echo $filenames; 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will grab all files with any extensions

```
glob($path . "/" . $filename ".*");
```

Add extension checking to skip .txt output

```
foreach (glob($path . "/" . $filename ".*") as $filenames)  {   
  if (!strpos($filenames, ".txt"))
    echo $filenames; 
}
```

Comment: Hi please see my question I have edited it and added some of my work, please reply to it.

Comment: Simply add extension checking to skip .txt output

Comment: Thanks ydoow your last comment  was a cherry on the cake.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
glob($path."/".$filename.".*");
```

See definition of glob function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 1):

try this

$folder = 'registrationimages/sliderimages/';

```
            $filetype = '*.*';
            $files = glob($folder.$filetype);
            $count = count($files);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
                echo $files[$i] ;
    }
```

Comment: Hi please see my question I have edited it and added some of my work, please reply to it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you are using some file let's say `A.txt` and you want to echo all files with same name but different extension in the same directory.

All you need to do is get the file directory and name without extension and use the [glob](http://php.net/glob) function.

```
// if $value is your full filename(path+filename+extension)
$dotPosition = strpos($value, '.');
$myExt = substr($value, $dotposition); // getting the extension
$myFile = substr($value, 0, $dotPosition); // this should crop the extension

foreach (glob("$myFile.*") as $filename) {
   if(strpos($filename, $myExt) == false){ // checking if it's different extension
      echo "$filename \n";
   }
}
```

The `*` symbol stands for any amount of any symbols -> any extension in your case.

I hope I got the question right and made this clear enough ;)

P.S.: You may notice that I just made a little edit to the example on the documentation site. Checking out the examples there usually helps a lot!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried `foreach (glob($value."*") as $filename) 
       {
         echo $filename "\n";
       }` but its showing only the text files.

Comment: Stupid question, but do you have any files in that directory with that filename which are not textfiles?

Comment: + make sure that your `$value` variable contains only the string directory and filename without extension. For example: `D:\fold\A` not `D:\fold\A.txt` !

Comment: @PranayB updated my answer, might be better now for you

Comment: Yes there are other files with the same name and the code is working but the code outputs both `.txt` & `.pdf` paths and files. Code: `$filename = basename($value, ".txt"); $value = "D:\\Fold\\A.txt";
$path = pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_DIRNAME) ."\\". $filename;
foreach (glob($path."*") as $filenames) 
{
  echo $filenames;
}`

Comment: @PranayB Ok, check out my whole code again, it shouldn't echo out the files with the extension of the given file now.

Comment: Feel free to vote up and accept if it's what you wanted. + Try to search the http://php.net/manual/en/ more because I'm sure you are able to figure out this on your own :)

Comment: Hi, your code is working if I set the `false` in `if(strpos($filename, $myExt) !== false)` to `true`. But it is showing all the files including the `.txt` file.

Comment: Hey I made a mistake in the if, now it should be correct. The `strpos` function will give false if it doesn't find the extension in the filename which should be good -> will echo only files without the extension of file you gave it in the beginning. Anyway gl&hf with PHP ;)

Comment: Thank you Ms. Nobody you helped me in all possible ways. thanks again.

Comment: I'm happy when I can be useful and I hope you will try to do more research on your own next time ;)